# Overloading operator << for standard containers

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I'd like to be able to write `<< name` for stl standard containers like `vector`, `map` etc, so I added to my include header definitions for `operator <<`, e.g.

```
template <class T>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss, std::vector<T> const& vec)
{
    auto it(begin(vec));
    if (it != end(vec))
        ss << *(it++);
    for (; it != end(vec); ++it)
        ss << " " << *it;
    return ss;
}
```

or `std::copy(cont.begin(), cont.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Type>(std::cout, " "));`

However, to use them, I always have to write `using ::operator<<;` as the operators aren't found.

As I use various namespaces, I can't just add them to all namespaces.

Ideally, I'd like to add them to `std`, which seems to work fine with visual studio, but then according to the standard this is undefined behavior.

Is this unofficially supported even though it isn't standard? Is there a better way to make them available without having to write `using ::operator<<;` everywhere and without knowing the namespace it is going to be used in in advance?

Comment: Could you add an example situation where it fails ? I don't see why that would happen if you declared it in the global namespace.

Comment: [Here is what I understood](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49e0578fef688e87), and works.

Comment: You might be interested in something like the [pretty printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850473/pretty-print-c-stl-containers).

Comment: @Quentin I don't know if this is what OP is talking about, but if you have a specialized `operator<<` in your namespace before the call to the templated `operator<<`, it will hide the templated version for vector (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/887519cabec80214).

Comment: @Holt good catch. I don't think there is any way around importing `::operator<<` back into the overload set though.

Comment: @Quentin: I modified your example to exemplify the problem: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9b5899bf480da83e

Comment: @KerrekSB: Thanks for the link, but unless I am misunderstanding they are simply going ahead and placing some stuff into the `std` namespace...

Comment: @Cookie: Yes, that's a problem. I don't think you can provide an overload completely unintrusively for something like `std::vector<int>`. But how about requiring just  a single line like `using namespace operators;`, and you stick all the using declarations into that namespace? That way users could opt in easily, but it'd still be explicit.